# In which comic issue was Superman ruler of hell?

Tags: dc, superman, episode-identification

The Wikipedia page for Lucifer (DC Comics) has the following to say:

> Two angels, several demons, a human, and briefly **Superman** have taken his place as ruler of Hell...

This is, I believe, after Lucifer leaves Hell, and his obligations as its lord, forever, in *Sandman: Season of the Mists*.

In which comic issue & under what circumstances was Superman ruler of hell?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The issue is Superman #666 published in October 2007. In short, a Kryptonian demon corrupted Superman to make him ruler of hell, but it turned out Clark had previously obtained a “false soul” to get corrupted in his place, allowing him to stay safe. Here's [a summary](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Superman_Vol_1_666).

[image]